# How to remove remaining value after symbol(_)

Tags: mysql

Im trying to remove remaining value with only having or contains a symbol(_), but it gives me failed output, can somebody help to fixed these query? thanks.

My table:

```
  +--------+
  | letter |
  +--------+
  |  abc_1 |
  |  abc_21|     
  |  ab_3  |
  |  abc   |
  |  a     |
  +--------+
```

My output is these, using also these query

```
SELECT left(letter,LOCATE('_',letter) - 1) FROM mytable where letter like '%_%'

  +--------+
  | letter |
  +--------+
  |  abc   |
  |  abc   |     
  |  ab    |
  |  null  |
  |  null  |
  +--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL LIKE statements a `_` is not an underscore, just like `%` isn't a percentage sign. `_` means "any character" and `%` means "any amount of characters".

> SQL pattern matching enables you to use “_” to match any single character and “%” to match an arbitrary number of characters (including zero characters).

(from [MySQL - Pattern matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html))

To avoid this, simply escape your underscore with a backslash:

```
SELECT left(letter,LOCATE('_',letter) - 1) FROM mytable where letter like '%\_%'
-- Escape it with a backslash!                                              ^
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I have gain some information from you, thanks for the help and explanation.